# Generating an unused number

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to generate a number that doesn't replace another already existed number in a json file (orders.json) but in my discord.js bot everytime the command which makes the number keeps making the same number 002 and even creates it again when it already exists replacing the data in the json file which makes alot of issues with me

```
const json = require('../../orders.json')
const keys = Object.keys(json).map(el => parseInt(el));
const nums = [];
let i = 1;

while (i < 999) {
  if (!keys.includes(i)) {
    nums.push(`${i}`.padStart(3, '0'));
  }

  i++;
}
orderID = nums[1]
```

the generated number is orderID and it's not supposed to replace the same one in the json file
for example the json file has data like this

```
{
    "002": "some data here"
}
```

now its supposed to create the number 003 since 002 already exists in the json file but it creates the same number replacing the data which causes alot of issues
this is used for a discord bot which writes "orders" by numbers which aren't supposed to do that

I have tried also something else

```
json = 
{ "001": "Something"
, "002": { "message": "And more stuff" }
, "003": 42
, "Suddenly": "Okay"
}

const keys = Object.keys(json).map(el => parseInt(el));

console.log(keys);

const nums = [];
i = 1;
while (i < 999) {
  if (!keys.includes(i)) {
    nums.push(`${i}`.padStart(3, '0'));
  }

  i++;
}
orderID = nums[0]

console.log(orderID);
```

with that code the console shows:

```
1
2
3
NaN
004
```

now I simply replaced `json =  { "001": "Something" , "002": { "message": "And more stuff" } , "003": 42 , "Suddenly": "Okay" }` with `const json = require ('../../orders.json')` while the orders.json has this data

```
{
    "001": { 
         "some data here"
     }
}
```

it only logs "001" which already exists in the json which is the issue I'm encountering now

Comment: sounds like you should use a database and not a JSON file. I am not sure how you would handle concurrency of two requests trying to add a new line.

Comment: When you replace it with the actual file, did you console.log and see what it spits out when you map it? What is keys? Did you verify the content? Hard for us to guess why it would fail.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try finding the largest key in the object ([`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)), then adding 1:

```js
let json = {
    "001": "Something"
    , "002": {"message": "And more stuff"}
    , "003": 42
    , "Suddenly": "Okay"
}


let new_number = (
    // Get Current Max value in object
    Math.max(
        ...Object.keys(json)
            .map(el => parseInt(el))
            .filter(Boolean)) + 1
).toString().padStart(3, '0');

// Found New Key
console.log(new_number);

// Use new key to update object
json[new_number] = "some data here";

console.log(json);
```